# Dataframe from List<String> in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

- Spark Version : 1.6.2
- Java Version: 7

I have a `List<String>` data. Something like:

```
[[dev, engg, 10000], [karthik, engg, 20000]..]
```

I know schema for this data.

```
name (String)
degree (String)
salary (Integer)
```

---

I tried:

```
JavaRDD<String> data = new JavaSparkContext(sc).parallelize(datas);
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json(data);
df.printSchema();
df.show(false);
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)


+-----------------------------+
|_corrupt_record              |
+-----------------------------+
|[dev, engg, 10000]           |
|[karthik, engg, 20000]       |
+-----------------------------+
```

Because `List<String>` is not a proper JSON.

**Do I need to create a proper JSON or is there any other way to do this?**

Comment: Why don't you create Java bean class containing those properties and then you can have ArrayList<beanClass Data> and then you can create dataframe using sqlContext.createDataFrame(List<?> data, Class<?> beanClass).

Comment: @abaghel creating Java bean class is not possible for every set of data.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create DataFrame from  `List<String>` and then use  `selectExpr` and `split` to get desired DataFrame.

```
public class SparkSample{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkSample").setMaster("local[*]");
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    SQLContext sqc = new SQLContext(jsc);
    // sample data
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    data.add("dev, engg, 10000");
    data.add("karthik, engg, 20000");
    // DataFrame
    DataFrame df = sqc.createDataset(data, Encoders.STRING()).toDF();
    df.printSchema();
    df.show();
    // Convert
    DataFrame df1 = df.selectExpr("split(value, ',')[0] as name", "split(value, ',')[1] as degree","split(value, ',')[2] as salary");
    df1.printSchema();
    df1.show(); 
   }
}
```

You will get below output.

```
root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)

+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|    dev, engg, 10000|
|karthik, engg, 20000|
+--------------------+

root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- degree: string (nullable = true)
 |-- salary: string (nullable = true)

+-------+------+------+
|   name|degree|salary|
+-------+------+------+
|    dev|  engg| 10000|
|karthik|  engg| 20000|
+-------+------+------+
```

The sample data you have provided has empty spaces. If you want to remove space and have the salary type as "integer" then you can use `trim` and `cast` function like below.

```
df1 = df1.select(trim(col("name")).as("name"),trim(col("degree")).‌​as("degree"),trim(co‌​l("salary")).cast("i‌​nteger").as("salary"‌​));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DataFrame createNGramDataFrame(JavaRDD<String> lines) {
 JavaRDD<Row> rows = lines.map(new Function<String, Row>(){
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4332903997027358601L;

    @Override
    public Row call(String line) throws Exception {
        return RowFactory.create(line.split("\\s+"));
    }
 });
 StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
        new StructField("words",
                DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.StringType), false,
                Metadata.empty()) });
 DataFrame wordDF = new SQLContext(jsc).createDataFrame(rows, schema);
 // build a bigram language model
 NGram transformer = new NGram().setInputCol("words")
        .setOutputCol("ngrams").setN(2);
 DataFrame ngramDF = transformer.transform(wordDF);
 ngramDF.show(10, false);
 return ngramDF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Task can be completed without JSON, on Scala:

```
val data = List("dev, engg, 10000", "karthik, engg, 20000")
val intialRdd = sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val splittedRDD = intialRdd.map(current => {
  val array = current.split(",")
  (array(0), array(1), array(2))
})
import sqlContext.implicits._
val dataframe = splittedRDD.toDF("name", "degree", "salary")
dataframe.show()
```

Output is:

```
+-------+------+------+
|   name|degree|salary|
+-------+------+------+
|    dev|  engg| 10000|
|karthik|  engg| 20000|
+-------+------+------+
```

Note: (array(0), array(1), array(2)) is a Scala Tuple

Comment: In addition, the tutorial at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema shows how you can manually define a schema, instead of using toDF which isn't as reliable.

Comment: https://spark-testing-java.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.0/Scala/data_preparation/dataset.html